# R-Studio - installing package knn error

Tags: r, package

I try to install the kknn package in R. It downloads the folder but whenever I use  `library(kknn)` I get:

> Error in library(kknn) : there is no package called ‘kknn’

---

```
install.packages("kknn") Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Ed/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/kknn_1.3.0.zip' Content type 'application/zip' length 321517 bytes (313 KB) downloaded 313 KB
```

package ‘kknn’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked Warning in install.packages : cannot remove prior installation of package ‘kknn’

The downloaded binary packages are in C:\Users\Ed\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWClNdR\downloaded_packages

```
library(kknn) Error in library(kknn) : there is no package called ‘kknn’
```

Any suggestions?

Many thanks

Ed

Comment: Did you mean 'knn' instead of 'kknn'?  Also, if you did mean kknn can you show the installation output?

Answer (score 3):

You may try:

```
install.packages("kknn")
library(kknn)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit:
goto R/win-library/3.2 folder, find the folder kknn and delete it. restart your R session then reinstall the package.

```
install.packages(kknn)
library(kknn)
```

Comment: Many thanks. I did that but unfortunately I get the same error.